# JavaScript - On click on undefined number of elements to toggle multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a table that needs to have an undefined number of rows that should display a set number of elements when clicked (in this case div, because I read that it's the best way to use toggle on tr). Best I could do is make it for an already set number of elements...

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/mpasd/2zwpjgq1/7/) - <del>This is with the set number of elements.</del>Working code..

<del>And this is all I got so far trying to figure it out.</del>
Working js code:

```
$('.warning').on('click', function(e) {
  var $ele = $(this).nextUntil('.warning').find('td > div');
    $ele.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

In this case, I need each clicked table row to display three corresponding divs.
Obviously, answer with jQuery but I would appreciate a solution in vanilla js as well.

EDIT: I am sorry, I neglected to mention I want to add a sliding animation. And slideToggle doesn't seem to work...

EDIT2: Marked best answer by Terry.
Changed fiddle to working code.

Comment: You mean that you want to toggle an unknown number of `.active` elements after each `.warning`? Just use `.nextUntil()` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can actually greatly simplify your markup for your table rows:

```
<tr class="hidden">
  <td>
    <div>Hidden.</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>Hidden.</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>Hidden.</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

...and use the following logic:

1. `.nextUntil('.warning')` to select the trailing `<tr>` after each `.warning` element. See the documentation for [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/).
2. Use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) to show/hide elements, without the need to use overly verbose CSS detection

Here is the logic above, written in jQuery:

```
$('.warning').on('click', function() {
    // Selects all siblings until the next `.warning` <tr>
    var $ele = $(this).nextUntil('.warning').find('td > div');
    $ele.slideToggle();
});
```

If you only want to target downstream `<tr>` that has the class `hidden` (useful in the scenario where there might be other irrelevant `<tr>`s in the way that you do not want to toggle), you might want to add an optional filter instead:

```
$('.warning').on('click', function() {
  // Selects all siblings until:
  // 1. the next `.warning` <tr>, and
  // 2. has the class "hidden"
  var $ele = $(this).nextUntil('.warning').filter(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('hidden');
  }).find('td > div');
  $ele.slideToggle();
});
```

Of course this means that you get strange stacked borders when hiding elements, because you are technically hiding the table row content, but not collapsing the table rows/cells themselves.

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.warning').on('click', function() {
    var $ele = $(this).nextUntil('.warning').filter(function() {
      return $(this).hasClass('hidden');
    }).find('td > div');
    $ele.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 75%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid #AEAEAE;
  padding: 0;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
}

.hidden td div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="warning">
      <td>Click to show</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="warning">
      <td>Click to show</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="warning">
      <td>Click to show</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing... I neglected to mention I want to apply a sliding effect... That's what's not working for me, toggle works just fine. And your code helps me a lot, thank you. If you could only add a sliding animation, such as slideToggle...

Comment: I'll throw this on the fire: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/vzgh1as2/

Answer (score 1):

`$(".warning").on("click", function() {` use jQuery `.on` will add the event to dynamic element (future generated element).

then find the next hidden and toggle will do the trick.

check the example:

```js
$(".warning").on("click", function() {
  var nextHidden = $(this).next('.hidden');
  nextHidden.find('div').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 75%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid #AEAEAE;
  padding: 0;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
}

.hidden div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="warning">
      <td>Click to show</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="active hidden">
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="warning">
      <td>Click to show</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="active hidden">
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="warning">
      <td>Click to show</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="active hidden">
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="">Hidden.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see below snippet , note that I've set all the hidden class , class='hidden' , it's usless to name each of them differntly :

```js
$(".warning").on("click",function(){
  $(this).nextUntil(".warning").find(".hidden").slideToggle();
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 75%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr, td {
  border: 2px solid #AEAEAE;
  padding: 0;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
}

.hidden, .hidden1, .hidden2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="warning">
          <td>Click to show</td> <td>Name</td> <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="warning">
          <td>Click to show</td> <td>Name</td> <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="warning">
          <td>Click to show</td> <td>Name</td> <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="hidden">Hidden.</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: support multiple tr active classes .. (like tree example )